# Accessing Parameters From A Polymorphic Enclosing Function Inside A Polymorphic Local Function

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to make a function polymorphic but I am running into the following problem.

The following function compiles:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.spire-math" %% "spire" % "0.10.1"

import spire.math._
import spire.implicits._

  def foo(a : Int, b : Int) : Int = {

    def bar(c : Int, d :Int) : Int = {
      c * b
    }
    a * bar(1,2)
  }
```

The basic idea here is one of local functions and being able to reference parameters from the enclosing function in the local function. However, if I try to make this function polymorphic as follows:

```
import spire.math._
import spire.implicits._

  def foo[A:Numeric] (a : A, b : A) : A = {

    def bar[A:Numeric](c : A, d :A) : A = {
      c * b
    }
    a * bar(1,2)
  }
```

---

```
<console>:22: error: overloaded method value * with alternatives:
  (rhs: Double)(implicit ev1: spire.algebra.Field[A(in method bar)])A(in method bar) <and>
  (rhs: Int)(implicit ev1: spire.algebra.Ring[A(in method bar)])A(in method bar) <and>
  (rhs: A(in method bar))A(in method bar)
 cannot be applied to (A(in method foo))
             c * b
               ^
```

I run into a problem where the compiler cannot resolve the multiplication operator inside the `bar` function. There are multiple implicit alternatives. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `bar` to be generic:

```
import spire.math._
import spire.implicits._

def foo[A: Numeric] (a: A, b: A) : A = {
  def bar(c: A, d: A) : A = {
    c * b
  }
  a * bar(1, 2)
}
```

You're only getting an error, though, because you've written `c * b` (while the second argument to `bar` is named `d`), which means you're trying to multiply the outer `A` and the inner generic `A`, without giving any evidence that they're related.